# Quiero hacer 4 select dinamicos con la misma funcion pero solo me funcionan 2 aravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

```
      <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('departa', 'Departamento:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
         <div class="col-lg-10">
        {!! Form::select('departamento',$departamento_honduras,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'departamento']) !!}
        </div>
        </div>
                         <br>
                         <br>

   <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('munic', 'Municipio:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
     <div class="col-lg-10">
    {!! Form::select('municipio',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'municipio']) !!}
                             </div>
                         </div>
```

**estos son mis otros 2 select y contienen lo mismo que los de arriba pero el problema es que solo me funcionan con los 2 primeros y no se por que**

```
  <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('departa', 'Departamento:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
         <div class="col-lg-10">
        {!! Form::select('departamento',$departamento_honduras,null,['placeholder'=>'Selecciona','id'=>'departamento']) !!}
        </div>
        </div>
                         <br>
                         <br>

   <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('munic', 'Municipio:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
     <div class="col-lg-10">
    {!! Form::select('municipio',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'municipio']) !!}
                             </div>
                         </div>
```

**esta es mi funcion la cual si me funciona con los primeros 2 pero ya con los otros 2 no y tienen el mismo id y eso alguien sabra la razon por que ya para los otros no funcionan estoy tratando de hacer algo asi en otra pantalla el problema es que tengo el mismo problema ya para el segundo select no trae los datos**

```
$("#departamento").change(function (event) {
    $.get("municipios_dinamico/"+event.target.value+"",function (response,id_departamento) {

         console.log(response);
        // $("#unidades").empty();
        $("#municipio").empty();
        for (i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            $("#municipio").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].nombre+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Repites el atributo `id="departamento"` y `id="municipio"` El atributo global id define un identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse en todo el documento. Su propósito es identificar el elemento al vincularlo (usando un identificador de fragmento), en scripts u hojas de estilo (con CSS).

Comment: Los cambié y hice  la misma función pero con un id diferentes pero tiene el mismo comportamiento como podría realizarlo más o menos

Comment: "pero tiene el mismo comportamiento" que comportamiento tiene?

Comment: No me funciona por ejemplo le cambié los id alos Select y realize otra función y lo único que le cambié fue el #departamanto y *#municipio lo demás se lo deje igual